# When we should use fragment and when we should use activity?

Tags: android

When we should use fragment and when we should use activity?
What was the purpose of fragments when it was launched?

Comment: have you tried copying and pasting the exact same title to a search engine ?

Comment: Fragments were introduced around the time Android tablets came to market. You can have 2 or more fragments on one Activity